# Can I get lex to put out a yylex() function with a different name?

Tags: parsing, lex

I want to have two lexers in one project, and I don't want to run into problems with having multiple yylex functions in the build. Can I make lex output with a different prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-Pprefix` parameter for flex in your makefile. Using `flex -Pfoo` you would effectively prefix all yy generated functions. Have a look at the [manual page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

flex lets you do that. Just define the YY_DECL macro. Dunno about actual Unix(tm) lex(1) though.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a C++ lexer. This means all the state information is held in an object.

Then it is just a matter of using the correct object!